# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ diverges whenever $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^nb_{2^n}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

**Is the following argument correct**?

**Proposition.** Given that $(b_n)$ is a decreasing sequence such that $b_n\ge 0,\forall n\ge 0$. Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ diverges whenever $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^nb_{2^n}$ diverges.

*Proof.* Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^nb_{2^n}$ diverges, then given any $M>0$, there exists a $k\in\mathbf{N}$ such that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}2^nb_{2^n}\ge M$$
from hypothesis we know that $(b_n)$ is decreasing consequently we have 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}2^nb_n\ge\sum_{n=1}^{k}2^nb_{2^n}\ge M$$
In addition it is not difficult to see that $1+2+2^2+2^4+\cdots+2^{k} = 2^{k+1}-1$ consequently 
$$(2^{k+1}-1)\sum_{n=1}^{k}b_n \ge\sum_{n=1}^{k}2^nb_n\ge\sum_{n=1}^{k}2^nb_{2^n}$$ 
implying $$\sum_{n=1}^{k}b_n\ge \frac{M}{2^{k+1}-1}$$
given this it follows that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ can be made arbitrarily large  and thus diverges.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are several errors. The equation $(2^{k+1}-1)\sum_{n=1}^{k}b_n = \sum_{n=1}^{k}2^nb_n$ is simply not right. More important, the overall outline is not clear - this *looks* like a proof that $\sum 2^n b_n$ diverges.

**Edit:** It turns out that that equation was a typo for $(2^{k+1}-1)\sum_{n=1}^{k}b_n \ge \sum_{n=1}^{k}2^nb_n$. Fine, but it doesn't matter, because the argument still does not prove what needs to be proved! What we have is a proof that $\lim_k (2^{k+1}-1)\sum_{n=1}^{k}b_n=\infty$. That does *not* imply $\lim_k\sum_1^k b_n=\infty$, (which is what we need to show), because $\lim_k 2^{k+1}=\infty$.

Or to put it another way: The final "given this it follows" does *not* follow, because $M/(2^{k+1}-1)\to0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Hint for a correct proof: 
$$b_3+b_4\ge b_4+b_4=\frac12 4b_4,$$
$$b_5+b_6+b_7+b_8\ge 4b_8=\frac12 8b_8,$$
etc.

Comment: Sorry but my intention was to write $(2^{k+1}-1)\sum_{n=1}^{k}b_n \ge \sum_{n=1}^{k}2^nb_n$

Comment: @AtifFarooq Doesn't make any difference,  the argument is still  just wrong. You need to show that for every $M$ you have $\sum_1^k b_n\ge M$ if $k$ is larger enough - showing $\sum_1^k b_n\ge M/2^{k+1}$ does not do that, because $M/2^{k+1}\to0$. See edit...

Comment: Based on your hint i have deduced that $\sum_{n=1}^{k}b_n \ge \sum_{n=1}^{2^k}2^nb_{2n}$ so if $\sum_{n=1}^{r}2^nb_{2n}\ge M$ will choosing a integer larger than $\log_{2}(r)$ work?

Comment: @AtifFarooq That inequality you say you deduced is wrong. Asking whether choosing $r$ greater than something will work makes no sense, because there is no "$r$" anywhere...

Comment: @AtifFarooq The inequality is also probably not what you meant. For example, with $k=2$ it says $b_1+b_2\ge 2b_2+4b_4+8b_8+16b_{16}$; surely you didn't mean to say _that_.

Comment: Ok so is it $\sum_{n=1}^{2^k}b_n \ge \sum_{n=1}^{k}2^nb_{2n}$?

Comment: @AtifFarooq That's much closer. Surely $b_{2n}$ was a typo for $b_{2^n}$. Not quite right. Write out what it says for $k=1$; it says $b_1+b_2\ge 2b_2$. Something almost like what you wrote is correct - probably with the right side replaced by $A+B\sum_{n=1}^k2^nb_{2^n}$ for two constants $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @AtifFarooq **Before** asking about your next version, write out what it says for $k=1$ and $k=2$ to see if it's correct in those two cases!

Comment: Got it thanks for your help !

Comment: @AtifFarooq Oops. Of course $b_1+b_2\ge 2b_2$ is right, sorry. But for $k=2$ the current version says $b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4\ge 2b_2+4b_4$, not right.